# How to measure the time spent on creating a new record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a model Post
In the views, I also want to display the time spent for recording a new post to the database.

How to measure the time spent on creating a new instance of @post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ruby's benchmark

```
timing = Benchmark.measure { Post.new }
```

[Benchmark Docs](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Benchmark/Tms.html)

Or you can use manual timing.

```
start = Time.now
@post = Post.new
finish = Time.now
timeTaken = finish - start
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gemfile

`gem 'rack-mini-profiler'`
`$ bundle`
And just restart your application to see where places you loosing time.

For futher informations http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler